# Visual Studio 2013 + Resharper, How to make a shortcut to batch rebuild all?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, resharper, keyboard-shortcuts, resharper-8.0

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate Update 2

I'm also using Resharper 8.2

I have 4 different build configurations.

What I currently do manually is click on Build -> Batch Build -> Select All -> Rebuild

I want a keyboard shortcut to do this all, ideally without any mouse clicks involvement.

Thanks a lot.

**Update:**

just found out I can reach batch build via alt + b + t , and then I press Tab, and then R

so the question now is how do I convert Alt+B+T+Tab+R into a shortcut ?

Comment: I'm a lonely question with no attention :(

Comment: You can assign your own keyboard shortcut to `Build.BatchBuild` but there is no way to set a shortcut to select all in the dialog box that pops up. Could you create a build script to do what you want?

Comment: ok, what if select all is chosen by default, would it be possible to batch build -> then rebuild ?

Comment: just found out I can reach batch build via alt + b + t , and then I press Tab, and then R will do what I need